# How to use string_agg?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have this method:

```
   public List<Object[]> allIncomeChannels(final List<String> list) {

        return entityManager.createQuery(
                "select  string_agg(a.logicalUnitIdent,',') idents, a.incomeChannel.code, a.logicalUnitIdent, a.keyword from IncomeChannelMapEntity a GROUP BY a.incomeChannel.code, a.logicalUnitCode,a.keyword",
                Object[].class).getResultList();

    }
```

But im getting error :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   idents near line 1, column 44

Any suggestion how can i fix this? Im using postgres

Comment: Please edit your question to include the database system you are using.

Comment: im using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `createNativeQuery()` method with a native query. Here is your updated code:

```
public List<Object[]> allIncomeChannels(final List<String> list) {
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            "select  string_agg(a.logicalUnitIdent,',') idents, a.incomeChannel.code, a.logicalUnitIdent, a.keyword from IncomeChannelMapEntity a GROUP BY a.incomeChannel.code, a.logicalUnitCode,a.keyword")
            .getResultList();
}
```

Replace the query with a native query here.

Comment: when im using this query im getting error : No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode \r\n +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode........

Comment: i dont know why but now im getting this error : ERROR: relation "incomechannelmapentity" does not exist

Comment: What is your table name?

Comment: table is call r_income_channel_map , but enttiy in java is IncomeChannelMapEntity

Comment: I think you should replace it with a native query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198680/discussion-between-none-and-mushif-ali-nawaz).

Answer (score 0):

In your query 'as' is missing after string_agg(a.logicalUnitIdent,',') function. It would be like this

```
"select  string_agg(a.logicalUnitIdent,',') as idents, a.incomeChannel.code,......"
```

Comment: if i use as im getting another error : No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode

Comment: I believe you are using HQL and IncomeChannelMapEntity is your Java object. Is 'idents' field available in your java object?

Comment: i dont have that filed, its alias